# Content script into Whatsapp web

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am trying to create a small extension for chrome. I want to use a content script in [web.whatsapp.com.](http://web.whatsapp.com)
My manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Hello world",
  "description": "Hello world",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://web.whatsapp.com*"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
      ]
}
```

My content_script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
     if (request.greeting == "hello")
            sendResponse({message: "hi"});
  });
```

I use these codes in my popup.js to test if the content-script is injected:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        if (response) {
            console.log("Already there");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Not there, inject contentscript");
        }
    });
});
```

And apparently it always prints `"Not there, inject contentscript"`. I also checked the `content script` in `developer tools` in `sources` tab, and could not find my script there.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: It seems you are missing a slash in your pattern, it should be `*://web.whatsapp.com/*`

Comment: @rsanchez because in web.whatsapp.com it is a one page application, so there wont be any subpage.

Comment: Rsanchez is correct; `*://web.whatsapp.com*` is a malformed [match pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns), `*://web.whatsapp.com/*` is the correct one - the slash **must** be present, the `*` path is optional. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: @Xan I've tried that and it doesn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might have named your content-script javascript file different from the one you have declared in manifest file.

In manifest file you have written :

```
{
    "content_scripts": [
       {
         "matches": ["*://web.whatsapp.com*"],
         "js": ["content_script.js"]
       } 
    ]
}
```

Replace underscore with hyphen, making it content-script.js

Comment: This is not the issue by the way. It was a typo when I input the question.